# Problems importing project as library components into Vue-cli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I am working on a "Design System / Storybook" in a Vue-cli project and I want to validate how it would work as a component library in a simple Vue-cli project.

Based on the Vue-cli documentation and some guides that I have found, I have followed the steps below:

- Change the file "main.js" that exports the components to be able to create the library (code below)
- Build the component library using the vue-cli-service script command with the "pack" option because I can't publish this project in NPM (it must be private), so I have to test it locally
- Import the package into a simple vue-cli project

Apparently everything works ok, the project compiles ok, the compressed file is generated, in the other project I installed ok, I imported ok, but when I render the simple vue-cli project I get the following error in Chrome console:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Alert>
       <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Note: Alert is one of my components of the Storybook project

Some details of my Storybook project:

**Storybook package-json.js**

```
{
  "name": "my-custom-storybook",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/my-custom-storybook.common.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/my-custom-storybook.umd.min.js",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --open",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "build-lib": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --inline-vue --name my-custom-storybook ./src/main.js && npm pack && mv ./my-custom-storybook- 0.1.0.tgz ../ ",
    "test: unit": "jest -u",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "i18n: report": "vue-cli-service i18n: report --src './src/**/*.?(js|vue)' --locales' ./src/locales/**/*. json '",
    "storybook: build": "vue-cli-service storybook: build -c config / storybook",
    "storybook: serve": "vue-cli-service storybook: serve -p 6006 -c config/storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
import Alert from '@/components/customComponents/Alert'
import Button from '@/components/uiComponents/Button'

export {
  Alert,
  Button
}

export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.component('Alert', Alert)
    Vue.component('Button', Button)
  }
}
```

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: 'en',
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
      localeDir: 'locals',
      enableInSFC: true
    }
  }
}
```

**Alert component**

```
<template>
  <v-alert
    type = "warning"
    close-icon = "$vuetify.icons.small"
    Light
    dense
    text
  >
    <strong> {{title}} </strong>
    {{message}}
  </v-alert>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  name: 'Alert',
  props: {
    / **
     * Setup the title to appear on alert component
     * /
    title: {
      default: '',
      type: String
    },
    / **
     * Setup the message to appear on alert component
     * /
    message: {
      default: '',
      type: String
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In the simple Vue-cli project, I use the following instructions to import the component on the page:

```
<template>
  <div class = "home">
    <img alt = "Vue logo" src = "../assets/logo.png" />
    <HelloWorld msg = "Welcome to Your Vue.js App" />
    <Alert message = "Error on doing thingies" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";
import Alert from "my-custom-storybook";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    Alert
  }
};
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import MyCustomStorybook from "my-custom-storybook";
import vuetify from "@/plugins/vuetify"; // path to vuetify export

import "my-custom-storybook/storybook-static/css/main.96521509.css";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(MyCustomStorybook);
new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

What I'm missing? Are there any settings that I didn't consider? Do I need to add more settings? I am totally lost with this problem, I need help please T_T

Thanks to everyone!
Cheers

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax you use in main.js - there's no `new Vue(.....)` anywhere in your code ...

Comment: I do the new Vue(....) in the file main.js in the project I import the Storybook as library like vuetify, etc. PS: I edited the subject and added the main.js file there, you can check how I import the storybook :)